# UITableViewCell textLabel and content view both visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a single label added to the content view (via Interface Builder). I'm unable to display both the text label and the my custom content view.

- Don't set textLabel's text → my content view's custom label is visible
- Set textLabel's text → my content view's custom label is not visible

Setting `UITableViewCell`'s textLabel text seems to make the content view not visible.

Is there a way to display both? I'm trying to create a table view cell that has a label to the left of the disclosure indicator. e.g.

[image]

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1430934/24396) seems to imply that it's not possible to use the built in label and a custom contentView.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. You are trying to add custom UILabel to cell?

Comment: @tleon I've already added a custom label to the content view. However, if I set the cell's textLabe (`cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo"`), then my custom label is not visible.

Comment: Did you set your cells style to custom?

Comment: Yes, it is set to custom from within Interface Builder