# Best approach for UITableViewCell with both a left and right label

Tags: ios, settings, uitableview

My app has several settings that multiple choice (e.g. an enum value). I want to replicate iOS' sound settings table view cell, where the name is on the left, the selected value on the right, followed by a disclosure indicator (`>`).

[image]

My approach so far has been to create a custom table view cell (`.xib` and custom `UITableViewCell` class), with a value label added to the cell's content view. However, it appears that using textLabel is incompatible with a custom content view (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686309/uitableviewcell-textlabel-and-content-view-both-visible) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430295/uitableview-subview-why-this-uilabel-is-not-visible/1430934#1430934)). My guess is assigning `textLabel?.text` causes content view to be overridden or hidden.

What's the best approach for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a custom cell. Use a plain old `UITableViewCell` but set the style to `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` - Objective-C or `Value1` - Swift.

The label on the left is the `textLabel` and the label on the right is the `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: Yup, it was spelled out the docs the whole time https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW14