# Control UITableViewCell's style

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to use a `UITableViewCell` as-is, but have it style as `Subtitle`. My understanding is that the style can only be set in the initializer. The problem is that the initializer is called implicitly, and I have no way to specify the style.

In my `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` I register the cell and reuse ID

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
```

Then in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("defaultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

`cell` is always non-nil. The alternative is to bypass cell reuse and always create a new instance

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
```

Is there a way to specific the style and get cell reuse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to bypass cell reuse to get what you want. Do it the old fashioned way.

Don't call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifer:`.

Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:forIndexPath:`.

When the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:` returns `nil`, you create the cell explicitly with the desired style.

Comment: Even with calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("defaultCell")`, it always returns non-nil

Comment: You must still be calling `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifer:` or other similar method.

Comment: Ahh I see. I am calling `registerClass` because without it I was getting `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier defaultCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`. However, calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` (without the forIndexPath) does indeed work without `registerClass`. Thanks!

Comment: What I'm really trying to build is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686628 , I'd love to get your opinion

Comment: This question has been answered. I'll take a look at your other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the style in the Storyboard.

[image]